# Post's problem. Can we find explicit intermediate r.e sets?

Tags: logic, computability, turing-machines

It is well known by now that there exists r.e sets which are not recursive but weaker than
the halting problem, yet, no explicit example is known (I think). Are there (mathematical) reasons to
believe this is "hard" or even impossible?

To make an analogy, finding a problem which is NP-intermediate would yield a solution to
P vs NP, and thus, is probably quite hard, and (if P = NP) not possible. And even for this
problem there are some "candidates" like the graph isomorphism problem, or the factoring of primes. Is there any known candidates for an explicit solution to Post's problem?

To put an example, take the famous Post Correspondence Problem (no to be confused with Post's problem in the title), but let's fix the number of tails/dominoes, let us say $n$ of them. It is known that if $n=2$, then the problem becomes decidable, and for $n\geq 5$ the problem was
proved undecidable by reducing the Halting problem to it, but as far as I'm aware, it is still open for $n=3,4$: [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem#Variants). Could it be that for $n=3$ or $n=4$,
the problem would yield an intermediate degree? That is, to be an undecidable problem for which the halting problem cannot be reduced to?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by an "explicit example"? These intermediate r.e. sets can be constructed using Post's priority method.

Comment: I mean something as I describe in the third paragraph.

Comment: So are you looking for a "naturally arising" example as opposed to one constructed for the purpose? Or is there something more specific about the known constructions that you don't accept?

Comment: To clarify Karl's comments, the various solutions to Post's problem (e.g. Friedberg-Muchnik) are **totally explicit**: they do produce examples of intermediate sets. They're not "**natural**" examples, though.

Comment: Trying to be more specific, I would like a set for which it's characteristic function can be defined in a "nice" way, whatever this "nice" means. Like the PCP example. So yes,  "naturally arising" would certainly suffice I think, but probably not a necessity.

Comment: @Karl Minor quibble: the priority method was not due to Post but rather Friedberg and Muchnik. Kleene-Post introduced the idea of *finite extension* arguments if I recall correctly, but priority arguments didn't show up until about ten years later and Post wasn't involved.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If I remember correctly Kleene and Post did actually use priority-like method's, just not the finite injury, as is called now.

Comment: @Average-user I wouldn't call Kleene-Post a priority argument - without injury, while requirements are addressed in a fixed order there's no sense in which one requirement has priority over another since they never conflict. But I suppose that's a matter of convention.